# Adding page-specific CSS to Rails Asset Pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

*This is a question that several people have asked before, but none of the questions were quite asked or answered in a way that I found helpful, so I'm writing the question and answer that I would have found helpful.*

---

I have a Rails 3.1+ app using the asset pipeline. There's one specific action that I want to have use different CSS. (In my specific case, I have a page that is intended to be printed, so it truly needs completely different CSS and does not need any Javascript.) Currently, I have only one application-specific CSS file. How do I add the new CSS file and direct the asset pipeline to use my file?

For example, right now, my `app/assets` looks like

```
app/assets
    /javascript
        application.js
        custom.js.coffee
    /css
        application.css
        custom.css.scss
```

I want to add a `print.css` file that is used by the view of a specific action. This view will not use the `application.css` file. How do I add `print.css`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I found this blog post to be very helpful: http://blog.seancarpenter.net/2012/11/05/page-specific-javascript-with-the-asset-pipeline/. My answer paraphrases what this blogger already wrote and fills in a few missing details.

---

First, it's important that you've read and understood [the Rails Guide to the Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html). Unfortunately, this guide doesn't clearly explain how to add action-specific assets, but it does cover some concepts you need to know. Made sure you understand these ideas:

- That the asset pipeline compiles Javascript, CSS, and other assets so that Rails servers can cache assets for better performance.
- That manifest files use commands like `require`, `require_tree`, and `require_self` to indicate which files are compiled together.
- That in order for the asset pipeline to work properly in production, you need to manually run `rake assets:precompile` to produce the compiled, minified assets in the `public` directory.

These ideas are the minimum "need-to-know" pieces of information about the asset pipeline. If you don't already understand these ideas, you don't have an "expert or enthusiast" level of knowledge about the pipeline, and unfortunately, SO isn't the right place to learn this stuff. Fortunately, the [the Rails Guide to the Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) is a short 15-minute read and can get you up to speed quickly if you need it.

---

Second, these are the changes you need to make in order to ensure that the asset pipeline correctly sees and handles your new `print.css` file.

Follow these steps:

1. Add your `print.css` file to `app/assets/css`.
2. You'll need to create a manifest file that will show Rails where to find `print.css`. You need to do this, even though you only have a single CSS file you're adding. This is an easy step:

   - Add a file called `print.js` to `app/assets/javascript`.
   - Add this line to `print.js`:

```
//= require print
```

This will be the only line in the entire `print.js` file. If I understand correctly, Rails expects manifest files to have the file extension `.js`, which is why we aren't using `print.css` as the manifest file.

3. We now need to instruct Rails to find and use the `print.js` manifest. Add the following line in your `config/application.rb` file:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( print.js )
```

4. We're almost finished! However, the already-present `application.js` manifest includes the line `//= require_tree .` which means that it will include your `print.css` file. This will cause your `print.css` styling to affect your entire site, not just the single view. There are two ways of dealing with this:

   - If `application.js` and `print.js` do not share any assets, you can use the `stub` command in your `application.js` to exclude the assets used in `print.js`. What this does is instruct `application.js` to remove any of the assets that `print.js` references from its own list of referenced files. Our modified `application.js` looks like:

```
(snip...)
require_tree .
stub print
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18647131/473792) for more information.

- If your `print.js` and `application.js` files share some assets, you'll need to move all of the assets used by `application.js` into subdirectories. I didn't do this myself, so I'm not the most help in this area. Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7273333/473792) for instructions.

---

Now we have included `print.css` in the asset pipeline. We now need to direct Rails to use `print.css` in your specific view.

Let's say your action is in the `reports` controller, and that the action is named `print_reports`. This means we have a `reports_controller.rb` file and a `print_reports.html.erb` (or `.haml`) file. We need to make several changes to these files.

1. To start, add a new layout in `app/views/layouts`. Perhaps call it `print.html.erb`. We'll use this new layout for your `print_reports.html.erb` file. Set it up as you desire. For a page intended to be printed, this will likely be very simple, such as

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title="Print">
    </head>
    <body>
        <%= yield %>
    </body>
</html>
```

Using a separate layout the disadvantage that it's difficult to keep this layout and the layout used by the rest of the application in sync, but if you are using separate CSS files for the action, it's unlikely that you want the layout to be the same anyway.

2. Add a `stylesheet_link_tag` in the layout's header pointing to your `print.css`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title="Print"/>
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag "print" %>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%= yield %>
    </body>
</html>
```

3. In the controller, we'll tell Rails to use our new layout for the action. Add the line `layout 'print', only: [:print_reports]` to your controller:

```
class reports_controller < ApplicationController
    layout 'print', only: [:print_reports]

    #snip
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3025784/473792) for more information and a few different approaches.

At this point, when you run the app, your `print_reports` action should be using `print.css` correctly!

---

Remember to run `rake assets:precompile` before deploying on the server.

Comment: You don't really need to add an extra JavaScript file. Just put `config.assets.precompile += %w( print.css )` in your config/application.rb and then precompile your assets as you would usually do.

Answer (score 5):

## Official Solution

It is documented in the official Rails Guides here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#controller-specific-assets

Actually you can leave out the require_tree directive (located in *application.css* and *application.js*) then use this in your template:

For controller specific JavaScript:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag params[:controller] %>
```

For controller specific CSS:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller] %>
```

Comment: `stylesheet_link_tag` generate <link> tag,  you can't use it inside <body>...  what's the purpose of this solution then?

Answer (score 3):

All of you are putting very complicated answers.

1 Go to app/assets/stylesheets
2.Make a file with the extension .css
3.Go to config/initializers/assets.rb
4.Put this line of of code `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( file.css )`
5.Replace `file.css` with the file you created
6.Go to your html.erb file
7.Type this in the `<head>`, `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "file" %>`
8.Replace `file` with the filename(no extension in the name)
Good Job you linked the file!

Comment: Thank you for the concise answer. If you're trying to use sass, replace file.css in step 4 with file.css.scss or file.scss depending on how you have the file saved in apps/assets/stylesheets. And then it's properly sent thru the asset pipeline. No headache!

Comment: That works great, but it's not valid. individual erb files don't have a <head> section. That's typically in the layout.

Comment: Separately to the main <head> section in my appliciation.html.erb file, I added another <head> section to a specific html.erb file and it works ok. Is there a reason not be doing this?

Comment: that's just malformed HTML. Please cross-check.. A single document can't have multiple <head> tags

Comment: This still makes it available everywhere.  However, if you put in the application.html.erb something like `<% if @fileCSS %><%= stylesheet_link_tag 'file' %><% end %>` and then put `@fileCSS = true` in the controller methods you want to "see" it, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

> There's one specific action that I want to have use different CSS.

Here's an alternative way to accomplish what you're looking for:

Add the controller name and action name to the app body in your */views/layouts/application.html.rb*:

```
<body class="<%= controller_name %>-<%= action_name %>">
  <%= yield %>
</body>
```

Then in your .scss file:

```
.controller_name-action_name {
  // your css goes here
}
```

So if your controller was *static_pages* and your action was *home*:

```
.static_pages-home {
  // your css goes here
}
```

Tada! Your css only appears for that specific action.

Comment: I like this idea, but I have the feeling that giving the user this information, i.e. the controller name and the action used in a specific page, is not a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

In your layout

```
<head>
  // ...
  <%= yield :stylesheets %>
</head>
```

In your view

```
<%= provide :stylesheets do %>
  // your page-specific css
<% end %>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: This should be the answer! It is so simple.  Include explanation -> "Here's how you add things to the head." Done