# Not all of my assets are being precompiled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I'm having problems precompiling my assets in a Rails 4 app. I followed the steps in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27206835/adding-page-specific-css-to-rails-asset-pipeline) to set up two different files in my asset pipeline that act as asset manifest files. In particular, in my `/app/assets/javascript` directory, I have two files, `application.js` and `meeting_handout.js` that act as manifest files. When I run `rake assets:precompile`, however, only the assets referenced from `application.js` are precompiled. I end up with the file `public/assets/application-HASH.css` being generated, but not the file `public/assets/meeting-handout-HASH.css`. What can I do to fix this?

The research I've done so far says to make sure that in `config/application.rb`, I include the following line:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( meeting_handout.js )
```

My `appliation.rb` does in fact have that line, but I'm still not getting the behavior I'm expecting.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already, you should also be sure to modify `application.js` as suggested in the linked answer (to either stub `meeting_handout.js`, or rearrange shared assets, as the additional links in the linked answer detail).

Comment: I followed the steps in the linked question to a T. (I actually wrote it after figuring out how to do everything on my own. Afterwards, I wrote exactly what I did, partly so I had an easy way to summarize what I did in case I needed to explain myself in the future!)

Comment: So `application.js` has definitely been modified? (That source wasn't included in your question, only `application.rb`, so just making sure! And if so, you might want to include that in your post as well.)

Comment: `application.js` has been modified, but `meeting_handout.css`, a file referenced by `meeting_handout.js` with a `//=require` line, has been modified too. I expect that when I run `rake assets:precompile`, my updated `meeting_handout.css` is precompiled into `public/meeting_handout-HASH.css`.

Comment: I see what you're saying. Yes, `application.js` has been modified to include `//= stub meeting_handout`.

Answer (score 1):

In `config/application.rb`, I changed

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( meeting_handout.js )
```

to

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( meeting_handout.css )
```

I wasn't using the `meeting_handout.js` file for anything besides referencing `meeting_handout.css`, and after looking at it more closely, it looks like `rake assets:precompile` was only ever compiling the `.js` file. Telling Rails to compile the `.css` file worked like I wanted it to.